# How can I retrieve two different values from firebase realtime database and use outside onDataChange method?

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-activity, fetch

```
   int percentint=(vdcostint/b1txtaint)*100;
```

-------vdcostint is a value retrieved from firebase and b1txtaint is another value from different key---

But I am unable to use two values outside onDataChange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you obtain inside onDataChange() are not available outside the method. To use the data outside those values you need to call a function from inside of the onDataChange() and do the calculations there.